# What is the beracha on gnocchi?

Tags: food, blessing

According to Wikipedia, this is Gnocchi: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnocchi

How do I know which beracha to make considering it is made from potatoes and is not a normal pasta? Should I just stick to she'hakol?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the ingredients in a particular gnocchi recipe?

Answer (score 4):

Gnocchi seem to be a form of pasta. See [here 1](http://www.ok.org/Content.asp?ID=117), if made from the five species of grain (wheat, barley, rye, oat or spelt), make "mezonot".

If made from one of the five species and potatoes (or anything else for that matter), we need to know why one of the five species was used. (See [here 2](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/25_cereals.html)).

If it is added to add taste or nutrition AND it can be tasted – it would be the main part (ikar) and the brocho on the gnocchi is Mezonot.

If it is merely added as a binding ingredient to maintain a certain consistency – it would be secondary (tofel) and the brocho on the gnocchi would be shehakol.

Regarding saying shehakol in a doubtful situation, see [here 3](http://westmountshul.com/documents/Review%20Sheet%203.pdf) which says, if you don't know which bracha to say because you didn't learn the halachot, you may not rely on on your lack of knowledge to say shehakol.. Rather, you should go and learn the halacha (or ask an authority) and then say the proper bracha.

Best is, of course, to CYLOR.

Comment: I believe the questioner is asking what to do when it is made from both. As it often is.

Comment: @avi Thanks. I have updated the answer to take account of your point.

Comment: ...and if made from only potatos say Shehakol.

Comment: About the penultimate paragraph: "go and learn the halacha" is the right thing to strive for, but that doesn't help when the plate of food is in front of you.  The person in this situation needs to know what to do by default until he learns better.

Comment: @MonicaCellio My source is "The Halochos of Brochos"  Rabbi Y P Bodner p234 (from the Shulchan Oruch - from the Gemoro). Unless I bypass the problem I may not eat the food until I know the brocho. Here the question will be whether the gnocchi need a brocho of Mezonot or Shehakol. By making these brochos first on other foods that I also want to eat (say a biscuit and a piece of cheese) with intention to cover the gnocchi in front of me, I will have solved the problem.

Comment: By "should I stick to she'hakol", I didn't mean just beacuse I don't know the halacha, but also because I don't know how those specific gnocchies are made! I rarely know the exact ingredients and quantities, and even less so the "intent" of each ingredient.

Comment: @nute Now we understand. Lack of information **will** lead you to she'hakol. For interest, I googled gnocchi kosher and found some recipes. If you made it yourself you might be able to determine the brocha but you don't have to do that!

Comment: I don't know, whether it still bothers anyone, but I've asked an Italian rabbi, and he said that the flour content was usually insignificant (at least in the Italian version). Usually factory made gnocchis don't contain actual potatoes, but some powders that are _shehakol._ Though, if you actually made gnocchi at home from real potatoes, it's _haadama._ [See also this question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43789/15256)

Comment: Yes @Kazibácsi It still bothers me so thank you for your comment - which could make an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Gnocchi is a type of pasta. Though it might also have mashed up potatoes in it (which would lead one to think "shehakol") it still has substantial amounts of flour which, I would think, makes it a mezonos.

Comment: according to this recipe, it's 1 c. flour for 2 lbs potatoes.  It serves 6, which means each serving has 1/6 c flour.  Is that enough for mezonot to be primary?

Comment: I don't know what counts to make flour an ikkar, but I saw this http://www.berachot.org/Q+A/index.html -- question 34. The distinction  the author made was that flour would be listed if there was "a substantial amount (meaning it comes up as one of the first several ingredients)". If you were to list all the ingredients in your gnocchi recipe by volume, flour would still rank rather high on the list.

Comment: _Mod Note: This answer was penned to a different version of this question and moved hither._

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on to Avrohom Yitzchok's answer with a source: See [here](http://www.brochos.com/item/225523) where it is quoted from the Sefer שערי הברכה that Gnocchi is Mezonos / Al Hamichya.

Answer (score 0):

On the Brachos site they quote Sefer Shaarei Habracha as ruling it is Mezonos

http://www.brochos.com/item/225523

Comment: Welcome to MY! Please consider reading my [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14688/what-is-the-beracha-on-gnocchi#comment302535_14690).

Answer (score -2):

Gnocchi will never be eaten alone, there will always be a lot of cheese and spices and those are very important ingredients, I would go with shehakol

Comment: That doesnt really make a difference in hilchos brachos. Mezonos is always considered the ikkar in a food mixture. Especially here where it is obvious that the pasta is the main part of the dish. Simply by the fact that on a restaurant menu it will say "gnocchi" and not "cheese with some pasta mixed in"

Comment: I would not say it is mezonos to begin with, it is from potato?

Comment: As far as I know, its a potato base wrapped in mezonos dough. That would be a mezonos, like ravioli

Comment: Ok,I understand, but there are recipes without flour, I make my own, here where I live there are no kosher Gnocchi to buy anyway