# What is the bracha for gnocchi?

Tags: food, blessing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the beracha on gnocchi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14688/what-is-the-beracha-on-gnocchi)

I'm not sure whether gnocchi have mezonos. Does anybody know? Also, if not, would they be haadama or shehakol?